# i want to redirect my website url

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website links are like;

```
mywebsite.org/index.php?k1=1
mywebsite.org/about-us.php?k2=1
mywebsite.org/services.php?k3=1
mywebsite.org/contact.php?k4=1
```

I want to change it like only my domain name shows with every page. Like if I click on about-us.php it will be like mywebsite.org. I have read many examples and tried many but not found a solution.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /about-us?k2=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be a easy solution : If you are concerned about the k value.

```
   <?php 
$basename = strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
if(!empty($basename)){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

In this rule `.*` refers to that everything after your url is redirected to index.php. And you have to remove all other .htaccess rules.

Comment: When providing an answer it is best to also provide some explanation about what your code does and where @OP went wrong as opposed to simply provided block code.

Comment: how can i create for my all pages?

Comment: try `mywebsite.org/about-us.php` like this it will show  at `mywebsite.org/index.php`